# Is the Mona Lisa in the Louvre the Real one

Tags: history, art

Is the Mona Lisa hanging in Paris/Louvre the real one? [There are "other versions" and copies that are well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mona_Lisa#Early_versions_and_copies). [It was stolen in 1911 after all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenzo_Peruggia), as well as [vandalized a couple of times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mona_Lisa#Theft_and_vandalism). There have been several people who have had occasion to ask if the Louvre is displaying the real painting (whether [for protection](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g187147-i14-k5109347-Is_the_Mona_Lisa_the_real_one-Paris_Ile_de_France.html) or that [a thief made off with the original](https://www.quora.com/If-the-Mona-Lisa-was-stolen-and-replaced-with-a-fake-would-the-French-government-reveal-that-it-is-missing)).

Comment: skeptics.SE, not conspiracy.SE...

Comment: Technically, there's a credible claim out there that it *is* the real Mona Lisa, and the post author can question it.  This isn't a well-written question, but I think it could be edited until it was.  @Shmuel why are you asking?

Comment: Did my edits help?

Comment: Technically, the format would be, first, to find a credible claim that the Louvre possesses the Mona Lisa, and then state a challenge to that claim.  In this particular case, having solid reasons to make the challenge would be helpful but are not technically necessary.  Generally, posts on discussion boards and question sites are meaningless as far as evidence, though.  You don't have any real support behind your challenge here.

Comment: I really couldn't find any discussion about the original askers claim. Most of the articles talk about versions of the painting Da Vinci did and the like.  I am not particularly aware of any reputable or widely believed claims that the painting is a fake as it wasn't really as widely regarded as a masterpiece until the 1911 theft attempt.

Comment: Yes @DevSolar I am skeptical that after being stolen it wouldn’t be the real painting.

Comment: A fantastic edit Mr. JasonR

Comment: In the days before an image could be faithfully reproduced it wasn't uncommon for an artist to paint the same image multiple times, or even have their students make copies.  If Da Vinci created multiple copies of the Mona Lisa which one qualifies as "the real one"?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mona_Lisa#Early_versions_and_copies

Comment: I don’t mean another version, I mean an exact duplicate of the one we’re looking at in Paris.

Comment: @Shmuel: If the duplicate is "exact", how would anybody be able to tell it's a duplicate?

Comment: Exact to the naked eye. Meaning, those other versions were nothing like the Mona Lisa besides that Mona was in it.

Comment: According to the [FAQ](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions), Skeptics.SE is for researching the evidence behind the claims you *hear or read*. This question appears to be *your own* speculation, and is off-topic. Please edit it to reference a claim that other people are making and flag for moderator attention to re-open (or get 5 re-open votes). @JasonR's edits, while helpful, don't have evidence of notable claims - just other people asking idly about the same speculation.

Comment: @DevSolar Carbon dating may be